# Is it possible to change vertical order of DOM elements visually using CSS which supports IE9+?

Tags: css

Without using flexbox or other techniques that would not work for IE9, is it possible to change the visual vertical order of DOM elemnts using CSS?

EDIT: I want to preserve document flow, so solutions involving absolute positioning or otherwise via precise coordinates and dimensions won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Not without some very precise `position: absolute`, I don't think.

Comment: I'm not very optimistic either. I'll add that position absolute doesn't work because I want normal document flow. Thanks, David.

Comment: Then I think you're stuck with using JavaScript (or, depending on the reasoning behind your re-ordering, possibly server-side scripting).